# Button/View still showing in ListView after setting it's visibility to View.Gone

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a `ListView` which displays different items to be purchased. If user selects an item, then I set  "`Buy`" and "`Add`" buttons as visible. When user clicks any other item then `Visibility` of previously selected "`Buy` and "`Add`" is set to `Gone`, and at the same time, I set `Visibility` of `Button`'s at selected list item to `Visible` again.

However, when i scroll listview for 2-3 times, then firstly selected list item does not hide (set visibility to `Gone`) "`Buy`" and "`Add`" `Button`s. Is it related to recycling of view ? I will show code here :

```
ButtonVisibilityFunction(View v) {
   if(mBuyButton!=null && mAddButton !=null) {
      mBuyButton.setVisibility(View.Gone); 
      mAddButton .setVisibility(View.Gone);
   }
      mBuyButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.Buy);
      mAddButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.Add);

      mBuyButton.setVisibility(View.Visible); 
      mAddButton .setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
```

I called above function in `mlistView.setonItemClickListner()`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by :  mAdapter.notifySetDataChanged(); !!

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known "problem". In fact, you need to understand how listview works exactly.
In order to save memory, only elements you are showing on the screen are live. The others are often destroyed and recreated when you scroll back to them.

Thats the reason why once you put your elements to be invisible, they are visible again, because they are recreated.

So, in order to put them invisible again, you need to do this each time your listview recreates your view.

To do that, you need to overrite the getView method and there set the needed elements to be hidden.

Comment: so for that I should check clicked position and do something like this  =>   if (selectedPositon != position) { set button visibility = Gone} else { set button visibility to visible }. is this right approach ?

Comment: In your getView, you don't have to check if the selectedPositon is the same as position. You can call the ButtonVisibilityFunction so each time your items will be created, the buttons will be corectly setup.